# Some questions on passwordless login functions

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, customer-community, verification, passwordless-login

If there is any documentation for these questions please let me know but for the life of me I can't fine it.  I created an lwc that implements passwordless login functions for email and I got it working.  But I have some questions:

1. are there any limits to the amount of times a user can use a passwordless login per day or hour?
   2)if a user does not receive an email and wants to resend the OTP, do I just invoke the unit passwords login function again to resend the OTP to the user?  Is there a limit to that? Or a better way to approach it?
2. are there any extra costs associated with the OTP or TOTP verification methods?
3. can I set the time before the TOTP is invalid? If so, how?  And if not, how much time does the user normally have for a TOTP?
4. are there any special permissions a user needs to verify using a TOTP or it exactly the same as an OTP verification methods needs?

Comment: Have you already checked the documentation here?  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_identity_passwordless_login_use_cases.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi David, I have :) there are no clear answers at all.  For instance, there is no documentation what so ever on resending the OTP from initpasswordlesslogin(Email)